# Why electrons accelarate in a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, inductance

The induced voltage in a solenoid equals to the applied voltage $U = L\frac{di}{dt}$.
From that I conclude that the electric field generated by the voltage supply and the induced electric field cancel out at each moment. So why do the electrons accelarate when there is a voltage across a solonoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect a solenoid to a battery, the net emf in the circuit will be
$$\mathscr E_{net}=\mathscr E_{batt}-L\frac{dI}{dt}.$$We know that $\mathscr E_{net}=IR$ when there is resistance $R$ in the circuit. When the resistance is negligible it is, I agree, usual to assume that $\mathscr E_{net}$ is zero.  I think this is almost, but not exactly, true. Some work is needed to accelerate the electrons.

Naïvely treating the free electrons as if they were in vacuo, we'd have $$e\frac {\mathscr E_{net}}{l}=m_e \frac{dv}{dt}$$
in which $l$ is the length of wire on the solenoid and $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is the electrons' acceleration. If $\frac{dI}{dt}=1\ \text {A s}^{-1}$ then in a copper wire of cross-sectional area 1 mm$^2$, $\frac{dv}{dt}\approx 10^{-4}\ \text {m s}^{-2}$. Even if $\ l=10$ km, we find that $\mathscr E_{net}\approx 10^{-10}$ V.

This calculation is crude in the extreme, but I think the point is clear that the net emf needed to accelerate the electrons, against their mechanical inertia, is negligible, and it is perfectly permissible to put $\mathscr E_{net}=0$ in the electrical equation. But the emfs (and the electric fields) in the wire do not *exactly* cancel, allowing the electrons to accelerate.

Comment: It is a very useful estimation that aids understanding. Even if the solenoid is superconducting, there will be some non-zero emf, probably because the induced electric field needs time to "react" on the changes of the magnetic field due to the current. But it is enough to accelerate the electrons, as your estimations show.